# Does osm2po support anchor tags with a colon?

Tags: osm2po

I have seen some tags in OpenStreetMap that contain colons. Example:

```
cycleway:right = lane
```

I have tried to add those tags as anchors "as is" in osm2po.config. For example:

```
wtr.tag.cycleway:right.lane =    1,  82, 15,  bike
```

However, I get the following error:

```
FATAL  Exception at Sat Jul 08 22:19:12 GMT 2017     
   Message: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "right.lane =    1"                    
   Class: java.lang.RuntimeException             
   Stacktrace:                                   
   de.cm.osm2po.converter.Tiler.open(Tiler.java:118)                                                  
   de.cm.osm2po.Main.runTiler(Main.java:227)     
   de.cm.osm2po.Main.main(Main.java:158)
```

Is this supported in **osm2po 5.1.0**? If not, what is the best way to set a clazz for edges with this kind of tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config is a Properties-File and Java does some annoying extra stuff here.
Setting the parameter on the commandline works well.
But declaring it in the config file needs a '\' to escape the Java-Trouble.
Try this:

```
wtr.tag.cycleway\:right.lane = 1,  82, 15,  bike
```